# Can a 24VDC operated DPDT relay operate in a circuit that has 1000VDC?

Tags: relay, switching, dpdt

Essentially, I am trying to come up with a circuit to automatically switch cabling configuration for a hi-pot test.

The DPDT will only be switched when the circuit is not energized using a separate 24Vdc source.

Can the relay handle 1000VDC during the actual test? No switching will take place while the circuit has been energized with 1000VDC (maybe 20 seconds per test.) [Link to the relay I was looking at for this purpose.](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/575/1/4058570000_RCL424024_en-3039396.pdf)

Comment: The relay you have linked to is rated for 250V  (AC) not 1000 VDC. If you make or break the connection while the contacts are powered, the contacts will likely fail in short order due to sparking.

Answer (score 5):

In general, a relay can be used for your application, but you need to select one that is rated for 1000VDC.  If you plan to use them when the circuit is energized, then double check the rating is for DC and not just AC.  It is far easier to break AC current than DC current.

The one you selected is rated for 250V only. Neither switching nor even isolation allows 1000VDC (screenshots from the datasheet you provided):

[image]

[image]

You need to find a relay suited for 1000VDC operation (go to any big electronics vendor (Digikey, Mouser, Farnel, RS, etc.) and filter by rated voltage. Most relays are for 250V maximum, but there are more than enough for higher voltages.

Comment: Note that rated voltage may be a type rating, i.e. including mains transients of relevant category. You'd have to look for standards cited, or ask the manufacturer, for further detail.

Comment: Indeed, there is some extra information about safety class 3, and different surge tests in the datasheet. But I'm definitively not going to advise OP to use a relay outside its nominal working range when playing with 1000V (it might work, or OP might get electrocuted : OP's life is certainly worth more than the cost of a 1000V rated relay)

Comment: Appreciate the insight. I reached out to the manufacturer to get some more information. Meanwhile I will look into one specifically rated for 1000Vdc.